# Which is correct *is; is being; was /were*?

Tags: passive-voice

A complete sentence:
**If only Anny [is; is being; was / were] a bit more reliable. Then we wouldn't have to wonder if the job is being done correctly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After expressions like "If only" and "Wish" we should use the subjunctive mood if we want to show something we want but unlikely to get.

If only she **were** more reliable (=She is not reliable. I wish she were, though).

Answer (score 0):

"If only Anny were a bit more reliable, we wouldn't have to wonder..."
That's the best formal expression. In ordinary speech, 'was' might be used.